# Groovy read most recent file in directory

Tags: file, groovy, directory

I just have a question about writing a function that will search a directory for the most recent log in a directory. I currently came up with one, but I'm wondering if there is a better (perhaps more proper) way of doing this.

I'm currently using hdsentinel to create logs on computer and placing the log in a directory. The logs are saved like so:

```
/directory/hdsentinel-computername-date

ie. C:/hdsentinel-owner-2010-11-11.txt
```

So I wrote a quick script that loops through certain variables to check for the most recent (within the past week) but after looking at it, I'm question how efficient and proper it is to do things this way.

Here is the script:

```
String directoryPath = "D:"
def computerName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostName
def dateToday = new Date()
def dateToString = String.format('%tm-%<td-%<tY', dateToday)
def fileExtension = ".txt"
def theFile


for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    dateToString = String.format('%tY-%<tm-%<td', dateToday.minus(i))
    fileName = "$directoryPath\\hdsentinel-$computerName-$dateToString$fileExtension"

    theFile = new File(fileName)

    if(theFile.exists()) {
        println fileName
        break;
    } else {
        println "Couldn't find the file: " + fileName
    }
}

theFile.eachLine { print it }
```

The script works fine, perhaps it has some flaws. I felt I should go ahead and ask what the typical route is for this type of thing before I continue with it.

All input is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though a bit messy, you could implement a multi-column sort via the 'groupBy' method (Expounding on Aaron's code)..

```
def today = new Date()
def recent = {file -> today - new Date(file.lastModified()) < 7}

new File('/yourDirectory/').listFiles().toList()
.findAll(recent)
.groupBy{it.name.split('-')[1]}
.collect{owner, logs -> logs.sort{a,b -> a.lastModified() <=> b.lastModified()} }
.flatten()
.each{ println "${new Date(it.lastModified())}  ${it.name}" }
```

This finds all logs created within the last week, groups them by owner name, and then sorts according to date modified.

If you have files other than logs in the directory, you may first need to grep for files containing 'hdsentinel.'

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
From the example you provided, I cannot determine if the least significant digit in the format:

> C:/hdsentinel-owner-2010-11-11.txt

represents the month or the day.  If the latter, sorting by file name would automatically prioritize by owner, and then by date created (without all of the chicanery of the above code).

**For Instance:**

```
new File('/directory').listFiles().toList().findAll(recent).sort{it.name}
```

Comment: +1, That's "groovy" (i.e., not readable), and it even conforms to the original "assignment by example" (that has been "amended" at a later stage). ;o) - Welcome at Stackoverflow, BTW! - SCNR

Comment: Very nice, I have had to go over it a few times to attempt to understand how it works. I'm having slight problems just getting the most recently modified for owner name. Where you print it out, I, instead check if(it.toString().contains(computerName)) however this still presents me with all files under that computer name. Is there a way to just get the most recent? I'm having trouble coming up with a way to compare them for some reason

Comment: You've got a few options to achieve that. The code I provided is grouping by owner, and producing a sorted list of logs for each. Removing the '.flatten()' would thus yield a list of sorted lists. With this, you could simply use .first() or .last() to get most/least recent.  Another possibility would be to replace the sort altogether, and instead use 'min' or 'max'. For example: "logs.min{log -> log.lastModified()}". If you only need one result per owner, there's really no need to go through the trouble of organizing by date.

Comment: new File("f:/example/").listFiles().toList().groupBy{f -> f.name.split('-')[1]}.values()*.max()

Comment: Wow, much appreciated! Thank you for the explanation. The first option only listed the most/least recent file overall in the folder (as opposed to each file per owner). The second and third option worked the way I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps some..This sorts a given path by date modified in a groovier way. The lists them out.

you can limit the list, and add other conditions in the closure to get the desired results

```
 new File('/').listFiles().sort() {
   a,b -> a.lastModified().compareTo b.lastModified()
 }.each {
     println  it.lastModified() + "  " + it.name
 }
```

Comment: I had originally avoided 'lastModified' due to there being multiple computer names. You say I can add conditions in the closure, how would one sort the files based on the computer name and then the date?

Answer (score 2):

As I was trying to solve a similar problem, learnt a much cleaner approach.

Define a closure for sorting

```
def fileSortCondition = { it.lastModified() }
```

And File.listFiles() has other variation which accepts FileFilter and FilenameFilter in Java, and these interfaces has a single method called accept, Implement the interface as a closure.

```
def fileNameFilter = { dir, filename ->
if(filename.matches(regrx))
    return true
else
    return false
} as FilenameFilter
```

And lastly

```
new File("C:\\Log_Dir").listFiles(fileNameFilter).sort(fileSortCondition).reverse()
```

Implement FileFilter interface if filtering is to be done by File attributes.

```
def fileFilter = {  file ->
        if(file.isDirectory())
             return false 
        else
            return true }  as FileFilter
```